# Maximum heap (program?) size

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I need to take in and process very large image buffers for a program I'm writing, so I ran a few quick tests to see approximately the maximum amount of heap storage I can use for my program.

Running the below code produces no errors.

```
uint64_t sz = 1; sz <<= 30;
uint8_t *test = new uint8_t[sz];
std::cout << "size is " << sz << " bytes.\n";
delete[] test;
```

However, if I left shift sz by 31 instead of 30, or if I create two test arrays with the above size, I receive a std::bad_alloc exception.

This seems to indicate that I can use a maximum of ~1GB of heap space, despite having a 64 bit system with 8GB of RAM. Is there a reason for this? Is this an alterable value? As my tags indicate, I'm runnings Windows and using Visual Studio. Ideally, I'd like to load as much of the buffer into RAM as possible without incurring swapping.

(As an aside, on my Mac running Yosemite, I can not only allocate this amount of heap storage, but can even write to it in short increments to force it all to *actually* be allocated (not just set aside by malloc) and subsequently read from it. Activity monitor reports 1, 2, 4, 8, 16... GB of RAM in use by the program, though the vast majority is compressed.)

Comment: Are you compling in 64 bit mode?  That is not the default in VS

Comment: Also note that these kind of experiments are not conclusive on all platforms; Linux, for example, will not fail on allocations larger than the available free memory size -- only when it's accessed will it be paged in, potentially forcing the OOM killer to stop a process in order to fulfill the paging request when it happens.

Comment: I actually had forgotten to configure my test project to output in 64-bit mode, and just thought I had because my main project was in 64-bit...

Comment: So that was a major derp. Sorry, and thank you. (As for Cameron's point, I did know that was true, which is why when testing on my Mac I forced it to actually load the memory. This was just preliminary testing. But thank you as well, as that's a valid point.)

Comment: Right, sorry, I hadn't read the last paragraph before I wrote the comment ;-) But do note that `1ULL << 31` bytes is 4GB, not 2.

Comment: Is that true? Isn't `1ULL<<31` = 2^31?